# Unable to sort list of files where the file name would contain the timestamp using Collections(Java)

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I have an arrayList that contains list of files, whose names are indeed timestamps.

```
List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
fileList.add(new File("20190612221053"));
fileList.add(new File("20190512221303"));
fileList.add(new File("20190612221353"));
fileList.add(new File("20190512222303"));
fileList.add(new File("20190612221303"));
```

The format of the time stamp is 'yyyymmddHHssmm'.

My objective is to sort this list in ascending order of the timestamps given in the file names.

Accordingly, I am using Collections.sort method as below:

```
Collections.sort(fileList, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
        Date timeStamp1=null,timeStamp2=null;
        try {
            timeStamp1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddHHssmm").parse(file1.getName());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            timeStamp2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddHHssmm").parse(file2.getName());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(timeStamp1!=null && timeStamp2!=null && timeStamp1.getTime()!=timeStamp2.getTime() ) {
            return (timeStamp1.getTime() > timeStamp2.getTime()) ? 1 : -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Obviously after this line, you'd expect the list items(files) to be in the order:

```
[20190512221303, 20190512222303, 20190612221053, 20190612221303, 20190612221353]
```

But instead I am getting the order:

```
[20190512221303, 20190612221303, 20190512222303, 20190612221053, 20190612221353]
```

CLearly something is going wrong.
Can somebody please point out where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: `return (timeStamp1.getTime() > timeStamp2.getTime()) ? 1 : -1;` --> `return Long.compare(timeStamp1.getTime(), timeStamp2.getTime();`

Comment: @JigarJoshi sorry, but still does not work. It gives the same result.

Comment: replace `mm`-->`MM` in your date pattern

Comment: @JigarJoshi Bulls eye. This ate up a lot of my time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two bugs major in the code

1. Comparison logic

Use

```
Long.compare(timeStamp1.getTime(), timeStamp2.getTime());
```

to do proper Comparison of two `long` numbers

2. Date pattern

switch `mm` --> `MM` for month.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using java 8:

```
List<File> ordered = fileList.sort((o1, o2) ->
    Long.valueOf(Long.valueOf(o1.getName()) - Long.valueOf(o2.getName())).intValue());
```

Basically you transform the file names into numbers (the yyyymmddHHssmm structure guarantees that newer files will have greater Long values) , then calculate the difference using a comparator and calling List#sort with said comparator

`ordered` will hold the ordered list of files

If you want reverse order then swap the operators like this:

`Long.valueOf(Long.valueOf(o2.getName()) - Long.valueOf(o1.getName())).intValue()`

---

## Edit

it's been noted that the filename structure goes like this:
**yyyymmddHHmmss_someName.extension**

Hence, the date value must first be extracted from the filename before perfoming the comparation.

In that case, the code should be:

```
    fileList.sort(
        (o1, o2) ->
            Long.valueOf(
                    Long.valueOf(o1.getName().split(Pattern.quote("_"))[0])
                        - Long.valueOf(o2.getName().split(Pattern.quote("_"))[0]))
                .intValue());
```

In this version the filename is splitted on the _ character the date reference is extracted. Then the date is converted into a number and is used to compare files.

---

## Edit2

If the filename is dynamic and it contains a **yyyymmddHHmmss** reference within the name, then you can do something like this:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{14}");

    fileList.sort(
        (o1, o2) -> {
          Matcher m1 = pattern.matcher(o1.getName());
          m1.find();
          String date1 = m1.group(0);
          Long num1 = Long.valueOf(date1);
          Matcher m2 = pattern.matcher(o2.getName());
          m2.find();
          String date2 = m2.group(0);
          Long num2 = Long.valueOf(date2);
          return Long.valueOf(num1 - num2).intValue();
        });
```

The date reference is extracted from any part of the filename.

You can add extra validations on the `.find()` calls to check if the filename respects the expected pattern.

---

## Edit3

The solution can be refined by adding filename pattern validation using Optional:

```
    long minVal = 19700101000000L ;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{14}");

    fileList.sort(
        (o1, o2) -> {
          Long num1 =
              Optional.of(pattern.matcher(o1.getName()))
                  .filter(Matcher::find)
                  .map(m -> Long.valueOf(m.group(0)))
                  .orElse(minVal);

          Long num2 =
              Optional.of(pattern.matcher(o2.getName()))
                  .filter(Matcher::find)
                  .map(m -> Long.valueOf(m.group(0)))
                  .orElse(minVal);

          return Long.valueOf(num1 - num2).intValue();
        });
```

In this solution if any of the filenames don't match the expected pattern, a default value of minVal (very old file date reference) is used.

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually I simplified my use case a bit here. In the mentioned example, the file name contains the timestamp directly. In my actual use, I need to extract it using regex and all. So thats the reason Comparator, which would allow me write such the logic(extract of timestamp from file name). Any other way would be appriciated

Comment: Ok, what's the filename structure? is it something like foo_yyyymmddHHssmm.txt ?

Comment: "20190612221353_all_items_consolidated.csv" to be precise

Comment: Actually the format is dynamic and so cant use static .split. But thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks for the help mate